# Efficiently concatenate and remove 1000 files at a time from a large directory

Tags: bash, shell, ls, cat

I know we can concatenate files by `cat file [file] [[file] ...] > joined-file`. I have a directory which contains lakhs (hundreds of thousands) of files. I want to concatenate a few set (1000) of files into one file. 
I have a file set that is very small in size. I want to concatenate 1000 files irrespective of their name and order so that it's easy for the other service to read and hold all the file names in memory to operate.

This is what I have tried

```
for i in /var/abc/*.csv; do "$i" > file1.csv; rm -rf "$i"; done
```

but to keep track of count another variable. What can be efficient method? 
So that I can't directly concatenate 1000 files and move them.

Why 1000? because the directory contains lakhs (hundreds of thousands) of files. We have each file size in 1-4 KB and just to make sure that the one output file size doesn't grow beyond a limit. I have tried this with your answers.

```
cd /var/abc 
for file in $(ls -p | grep -v / | tail -1000); do cat "$file" >>"/var/abcd/xigzag"$tick".csv" && rm -rf "$file"; done
```

Comment: Why do you need to count them ? Like a progress bar?

Comment: If you use ">" twice then the file is truncated before the 2nd file is written.  If you wish to concatenate files you need to use ">>", like `touch /root/all.csv; cat /var/abc/*.csv >> /root/all.csv`.

Comment: You say "size of file matters."  How does it matter?  What constraints are imposed because of file size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to loop, you can tell `cat` to read all the files:

```
cat /var/abc/*.csv > file1.csv && rm /var/abc/*.csv
```

as long as there aren't too many files (but the limit is huge).

Using `&&` between the two commands ensures the files are only deleted if they were successfully "copied".

There are a few caveats though:

- you mustn't run this in the same folder as the original files you're concatenating, otherwise the `rm` will delete the agregate and you'll lose everything;
- if new CSV files appear between the start of the `cat` and the expansion of `rm`'s arguments, they'll be deleted without being copied;
- if any of the CSV files are modified after they have been concatenated, those modifications will be lost.

You can mitigate the first two caveats by storing the list of files before creating the output file:

```sh
set -- /var/abc/*.csv
cat -- "$@" > file1.csv && rm -- "$@"
```

This will still lose any changes made to files after they have been copied.

To concatenate files 1000 at a time (so one resulting CSV per 1000 original CSV), with any number of files you'd proceed as follows, in the target directory:

```
find /var/abc -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*.csv | split -d -l 1000 - csvlists
for file in csvlists*; do cat $(cat $file) > concat${file##csvlists}.csv && rm $(cat $file); done
```

This will find all the files in `/var/abc` named `*.csv`, and list them 1000 at a time in files starting with `csvlists` (`csvlists00`, `csvlists01`...). Then the `for` loop reads each file list and concatenates the listed CSV files in a file named `concat00.csv` etc. to match the list. Once each set of files is copied, the original files are deleted.

This version assumes that the CSV files' names don't contain spaces, newlines and so on.

Comment: As soon as I read the first two lines of your answer, I saw the race condition (the ``rm`` will obliterate any file created while the `cat` is running). I was going to comment to point it out, so I was glad to see that you already disclosed it. (1) You can (at least partially) mitigate that by saying `sh -c 'cat -- "$@" > file1.csv  &&  rm -- "$@"'  sh  /var/abc/*.csv`. (And, yeah, you don’t need the “`--`” when you’re using absolute pathnames, but let’s teach people good habits.) (2) Even with my modification, this loses data if a file is modified while the `cat` is running.

Comment: Thanks @G-Man, I’ve added a variant of that using `set --`.

Answer (score 1):

Your command looks almost fine. Just add a `cat` and `>>` to actually append the content:

```
for i in /var/abc/*.csv; do cat "$i" >> file1.csv && rm -rf "$i";done
```

I don't quite understand the counting part. You could do something like this:

```
let count=0
for i in /var/abc/*.csv; do
  cat "$i" >> file1.csv && rm -rf "$i"
  let count++
done
echo $count files processed.
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
files=(/var/abc/*.csv(N.))
n=0
while (($#files)) {
  cat $files[1,1000] > file$((++n)).csv &&
    rm -f $files[1,1000] || break
  files[1,1000]=()
}
```